# Error event listeners not working on web components / custom elements

Tags: javascript, error-handling, dom-events, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to attach `unhandledrejection` and `error` event listeners to a web component. The goal is to have a general error handler for any error within the component.

With the code below, listeners are present but don't trigger.
If I attach them to the `window`, it works as expected. But I cannot use it because the host application may have its own error handler.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Error listeners</title>
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script>
        class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
                this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
                     <div>See console. Expected: 'Error captured by Custom Element:' </div>
                `;
                this.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', this.handleErrorFromCustomElement);
                this.addEventListener('error', this.handleErrorFromCustomElement);

            }
            handleErrorFromCustomElement(e) {
                console.log('Error captured by Custom Element:', e);// Not triggering
            }
            throwAnError() {
                 return neverDefined.unexistingValue;
            }
        }

        customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
        customElements.whenDefined('my-element').then(() => {
            document.querySelector('my-element').throwAnError();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As seen in the image, the event listeners are there. They just don't react.
[image]

If instead of `this.addEventListener` I use `window.addEventListener`, it works. But again, I need it at the element level.

Comment: What kind of error do you expect?

Comment: Exceptions in your script cause errors to be fired on the `window` object, not on some specific component.

Comment: I updated the question with the goal pursued and the error in the component to be clearer. The error is produced in the component's code/state. Is there a way to capture errors produced in the component's execution?

Comment: Wrap it in a ``try..catch`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: The point is to create a "catchall" to avoid using `try..catch` everywhere. I believe errors bubble up, and I want to catch the unhandled ones at the constructor level.

Comment: @danielp it would work like this if you would call the function in constructor, but you are using `addEventListener`

Comment: @danielp You can decorate all your methods to handle errors by calling `handleErrorFromCustomElement`

Comment: @danielp I'm running into the same problem. Did you end up solving this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `catch`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Error listeners</title>
</head>
<body>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script>
        class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                super();
                this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
                this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
                     <div>See console. Expected: 'Error captured by Custom Element:' </div>
                `;
                this.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', this.handleErrorFromCustomElement);
                this.addEventListener('error', this.handleErrorFromCustomElement);

            }
            handleErrorFromCustomElement(e) {
                console.log('Error captured by Custom Element:', e);// Not triggering
            }
            throwAnError() {
                 return neverDefined.unexistingValue;
            }
        }

        customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
        customElements.whenDefined('my-element').then(() => {
            document.querySelector('my-element').throwAnError();
        }).catch(error => console.log('An error'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```